# Moving a Compile/Make project from old RedHat 5 (CentOS) to modern Ubuntu/Mint

Tags: rhel, make, c++

So I have a little learning project that I am currently working on.

I have a project/program that is compiled up from multiple *.cpp *.hpp etc files. This project (actual bin-executable) is built using Make (CMakeLists.txt is present). The project is running on an old RedHat 5 OS 64 and was made back in 2013. I am trying to figure out how would one even go about to move this entire project and re-compile onto a modern OS (Like Ubuntu or Mint 19.3 64x).

**1.** What would be even the first steps to go about this?

**2.** Is there a way to 'scan' the Make project setup files and "see" what libraries, components, programs are required?

**3.** Running `ldd` on the executable shows the needed libraries ....

I am not an expert programmer (just an amateur, even less than that).

Comment: This sounds like fun! My first step would be to just try and compile it and see what happens. If it's a reasonably large project, it's very likely that you will get the requirements from the compilation error messages. Six years isn't all that long and many libraries are backward compatible so it may Just Work™.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `ldd` is a good starting point. In case RHEL 5 already has `yum whatprovides` it would be pretty easy to transform the ldd output into a list of packages that will be needed to compile the software.

Be aware that `CMakeList.txt` corresponds with `cmake` and not directly with `make`. `cmake` generates the `Makefile` which is then executed by `make`.

On the new system start with installing `cmake` and the list of packages determined before. Depending on the project type and dependencies this could be easy, or even impossible.
In case your project uses e.g QT3 it could be that on RHEL7 e.g there is only QT4. Such dependency issue will need modifications on the project files.

Copy over the files, and try to start with `cmake .` followed by `make`. In case you see errors for missing `.h` files, try again `yum whatprovides` to find the needed package.

Good luck, as there might be more stumble stones along the way. :-)